# Did Dave Elman contribute to an open heart surgery with hypnosis as the only anesthetic?

Tags: medical-science, psychology, hypnotism, pain

> [Colonel H.L. Elman (Dave's son):](http://www.daveelmaninduction.com/NGH_Notes.html) Among my father's many accomplishments,  one that I treasure is the story of the man who was too weak for ANY of the many kinds of anesthesia drugs available in the 1950's.  This man required open heart surgery immediately.  His surgeon and his anesthesiologist conferred.  At least one,  perhaps both,  was a student of Dad's.  They called to say their only course would be to use hypnosis,  but could Dad come into the operating room as their 'coach?'   He did,  and it was the start of a large number of similar cases.

Did that open heart surgery without conventional anesthetics happen?

Comment: Only thing I've found with a casual search is that the evidence is entirely in David Elman's book, which Wikipedia sees as somewhat unreliable.